# pasar contenedores docker a docker compose

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

me pasa que cuando paso mis sentencias docker a configuración de docker-compose el contenedor de nginx no funciona, pero si utilizo comandos docker run para levantar los contenedores si funciona, o sea levantando los contenedores a mano puedo ver el sitio de wordpress pero si los levanto mediante el docker-compose queda el sitio cargando por un tiempo y me da **504 Gateway Time-out**.

Estos son los comando docker:

```
docker run -d --name php -v /home/web-wp/conf/php:/usr/local/etc/php -v /home/web-wp/wp:/var/www/html php_fpm_72:latest
docker run -d --name nginx -v /home/web-wp/conf/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v /home/web-wp/wp:/var/www/html -v /home/web-wp/logs:/var/log/nginx -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --link php nginx:1.17.5
docker run -d --name mysql -v /home/web-wp//mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7.14
```

y este seria el equivalente docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.14
        volumes:
           - /home/web-wp/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
        expose:
           - "3306"
    php:
        build: ./docker
        image: php_fpm_72:latest
        volumes:
           - /home/web-wp/conf/php:/usr/local/etc/php
           - /home/web-wp/wp:/var/www/html
    web:
       depends_on: 
           - php
           - mysql
       image: nginx:1.17.5
       container_name: web_ingresantes
       volumes:
           - /home/web-wp/conf/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
           - /home/web-wp/wp:/var/www/html
           - /home/web-wp/logs:/var/log/nginx
       links:
           - php
       ports:
           - "80:80"
           - "443:443"
```

Me ayudan?
Gracias!

Comment: tu web debe tener la conexion a base de datos por el contenedor antes tendrias algo como localhost:3306 ahora debe cambiar a `containername:port ` , el caso de mysql es `mysql:3306`

Comment: Si podes agregar el `config.d` de tu nginx.

Comment: Has pensado en poner un proxy? Creo que te ahorrarías muchos dolores de cabeza

Answer (score 0):

Pasa porque a veces el docker-compose no toma los cambios hechos en el Dockerfile. En ese caso puedes pasar el siguiente código para ejecutar tus contenedores con docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
```

Comment: Usar `docker-compose up -d --build` para Dockerfile creo que es mejor que lo que propones. Aparte de que usar `--force-recreate` no tiene nada que ver con Dockerfile y es/puede ser complementario de `--build`

Answer (score 0):

Tu configuración compose parece estar bien, creo que tu problema radica en la configuración de proxy reverse en nginx.

te sugiero agregar configuración de red a tu compose:

```
version: "3"
networks:
  service_net:
    name: service_net
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.10.20.0/24
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.14
    volumes:
        - /home/web-wp/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      service_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.20.10
  php:
    build: ./docker
    image: php_fpm_72:latest
    volumes:
        - /home/web-wp/conf/php:/usr/local/etc/php
        - /home/web-wp/wp:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      service_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.20.11 # <-- php service ip
  web:
    depends_on: 
      - php
      - mysql
    image: nginx:1.17.5
    container_name: web_ingresantes
    volumes:
      - /home/web-wp/conf/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /home/web-wp/wp:/var/www/html
      - /home/web-wp/logs:/var/log/nginx
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      service_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.20.12
```

luego aplica a tu proxy reverse la regla en concordancia a tu configuración de red

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    auth_basic off;
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 172.10.20.11:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```